# .htaccess two old URLs to one new

Tags: .htaccess

I'm rewriting a website with a larger google cache.

So my Problem is that the old links should be reachable but under a new URL.
I'm sitting since 8h to rewrite the URLs with htaccess... But it seems to be to hard for me, so how can I make this:

old htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^banana/(.*).htm$ https://example.com/banana/index.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Future config wish:

```
1. https://example.com/banana/Berlin.htm
2. https://example.com/banana/index.php?id=Berlin 

both leading to -->     https://example.com/banana.php?id=Berlin
```

working .htaccess for rewrite 1:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/banana           [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) https://example.com/banana.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

working .htaccess for rewrite 2:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^banana/(.*).htm$ https://example.com/banana.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But either I run into Too many redirects or to not working rewrites...

And when i got one config working fine the oder old URL is pointing to 404 ...

Thank you in advance and very much!

Comment: have you tried 301 redirect? `Redirect 301 /banana/Berlin.htm https://example.com/banana/index.php?id=Berlin`

Comment: not yet, but this will not redirect to the target URL

https://example.com/banana.php?id=Berlin

Comment: of course it does. with the above line it will redirect the `/banana/Berlin.htm` -> `https://examples.com/banana/index.php?id=Berlin`   - Redirecting needs as first value the old path (not url) you trying to adress and then the new url or path. The .htaccess file needs to sit in the root of the website of course. PS dont redirect/rewrite a site to the very same url. You end in a loop.

Comment: Hi, sorry, yes of course it will redirect, my hosted environment is strange preconfigured...

I tried some hours after I found out that the problem I'm running into is: The target-php-file has the same name as the old directory.

So, do I have to rename the `banana.php` to `apple.php` or is there any nice trick to get it working?

btw I disabled the `mod_speling`, that let me get further problems with autocompletion.